# Gitlab runner using builded files from depency job

Tags: .net, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

So, I have a build stage and after a test and a deploy stage.
Now I read about the artifcat and saving the builded files in there. Buth the problem is that the project is really big (.net) so the builded files are +1GB. So the artificat didn't really work and was painfully slow.

**Is there another way that I can skip building every step?**

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  
build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - '& Write-Host "Restoring release build..."'
  - '& $env:NUGET restore "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  - '& Write-Host "Starting release build..."'
  - '& $env:MSBUILD /consoleloggerparameters:Summary /verbosity:quiet /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Release /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /nr:false "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  cache:
    paths:
      - Project/packages/
  tags:
    - windows
      
test:unit:
  stage: test
  script:
  - '& Write-Host "Running unit tests..."'
  - '& $env:NUGET restore "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  - '& $env:MSBUILD /consoleloggerparameters:Summary /verbosity:quiet /maxcpucount /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:PreBuildEvent= /p:PostBuildEvent= "$env:UNITTEST_PROJECT\$env:UNITTEST_PROJECT.csproj"'
  - '& $env:NUNIT ".\$env:UNITTEST\$env:UNITTEST_PROJECT.dll"'
  dependencies: 
    - build
  cache:
    paths:
      - Project/packages/
  tags:
    - windows
    
test:integration:
  stage: test
  script:
  - '& Write-Host "Running integration tests..."'
  - '& $env:NUGET restore "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  - '& $env:MSBUILD /consoleloggerparameters:Summary /verbosity:quiet /maxcpucount /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:PreBuildEvent= /p:PostBuildEvent= "$env:INTEGRATIONTEST_PROJECT\$env:INTEGRATIONTEST_PROJECT.csproj"'
##  - '& $env:NUNIT ".\$env:INTEGRATIONTEST\$env:INTEGRATIONTEST_PROJECT.dll"'
  dependencies: 
    - build
  cache:
    paths:
      - Project/packages/
  only:
    - triggers
    - schedules
    - tags
    - master
  tags:
    - windows
    
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - '& Write-Host "Restoring release build..."'
  - '& $env:NUGET restore "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  - '& Write-Host "Starting release build..."'
  - '& $env:MSBUILD /consoleloggerparameters:Summary /verbosity:quiet /maxcpucount /nologo /property:Configuration=Release /p:AllowUnsafeBlocks=true /nr:false "$env:SOLUTION.sln"'
  - '& echo deploy'
  dependencies: 
    - build
    - test:unit
    - test:integration
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - tags
  tags:
    - windows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shell runner` for your stages (as far as i can see you are already using it).

Save build 'artifacts' directly on your server in folder with name something like commit sha or just 'build'. In this case you should add `GIT_STRATEGY: none` for test and deploy stages (as you don't need to copy the repository after build). If you want to deploy to another server, you can use gitlab artifacts or use your own file-server to store builds and then copy from, or copy files to your production server directly from build server.

There is a need for adding 'clean' stage and free space from build files (or just clean folder on build stage)